# How to save Robot test reports in different directories after each MultiJob Phase in Jenkins

Tags: testing, jenkins, robotframework

I have a MultiJob configured in my Jenkins account.
I'd like to save my Robot test reports after each MuiltJob Phase if possible in different directories.
Is this possible? How can I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [robot framework user guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#output-directory), you can use the `-D` or `--outputdir` command line option to specify which folder your output files go to. In addition, you can specify the path individually for the log file (`-l`, `--log`) and report file (`r`, `--report`).